# Getting errors with python-pep8

Tags: python, linux

When I am running the command sudo apt autoremove, I am getting the following error with the package python-pep8.  I also get the same error when I try to install something.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-pep8 (1.7.0-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 38, in <module>
    from debpython.namespace import add_namespace_files
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/namespace.py", line 120
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package python-pep8 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pep8
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This is python2.7 syntax, but you are executing it with python3.XX. I don't know why, but somehow you broke your installation

Comment: @dgan how to solve it? I'm pretty new to it!

Comment: you should use python2.7 as default interpreter. Your `/usr/bin/python` must point to a `python2` or `python2.7`. If you re lucky, that will solve it. Otherwise, difficult to say, I d reinstall everything :)

Comment: I think I changed something (`nano ~/.bashrc`) but I don't remember what I have changed!

Comment: Then it's easy. Renamed your `.bashrc` to something else like `.bashrc.old`, and copy a new `.bashrc` from here `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. Then start a new fresh terminal, and try to execute the same command as before. If it works, it means, indeed, problem was in `.bashrc`. If not, it's something else. I doubt however that would help, but hey, try

Comment: @dgan, How do I use python 2.7 as default?